# Ionic 3 build not updating -- Android/Mac

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

I had Ionic 3 working fine for several months, and last week updated to Ionic 4 to test it. My app is written with Ionic 3. Now, `ionic cordova build android` doesn't update the build. Ionic serve works fine.

I'm able to run `ionic cordova build android` as well as all other ionic commands with no errors, but when I run build, the build doesn't update. The only way to get it to update is to remove and re-add the platform. I've also made sure to uninstall the app from the emulator after it runs -- so it's not accessing an older version. In addition, in the `/platforms/android` folder, none of the files were updated.

I've tried the following:

- Reinstalled npm/node (and with it ionic and cordova) through brew
- re-cloned git project
- reinstalled Android Studio
- reinstalled Gradle (also through brew)
- restarted the computer after doing all the above.
- reset the PATH variables (below) and tried running the build with Ionic-cli 3.20.* and 4.0.5.

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.5 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v10.8.0 (/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.8.0/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.3.0
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : /Users/eli/Library/Android/sdk
```

Path (in `~/.bash_profile`):

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/eli/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: I seem to have the same. I fixed a bug and it works when using ìonic serve` but when I run `cordova run android` and onstall the .apk, the bug isn't fixed. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: I am currently having the same issues. I have removed the platforms, added the platforms back, and even cleared the cache.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ionic 4, you can not convert from 3 to 4. system automaticly ask to you 'new version, do you want to upgrade ionic 4',but it can not upgrade your project. if you want upgrade your project from 3 to 4, first of all you have to create ionic 4 project and all copies to new project from ionic 3. if you want search some information , you can find ;
https://moduscreate.com/blog/upgrading-an-ionic-3-application-to-ionic-4/

if you don't want upgrade your app , you can uninstall version 4 and re install version 3

```
npm uninstall -g ionic@4
npm install -g ionic@3
```